# How to make progress_message more accurate?

Tags: 8, batch-operations

In the `submitForm` of `MembershipSettings`, I run a batch:

```
      $operations = [];

      << some query on an custom entity >>
      $results = $query->execute();
      foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
        $operations[] = ['\Drupal\association\Form\MembershipSettings::updateMember', [$result]];
        $iNumber++;
      }

      $operations[] = ['\Drupal\association\Form\MembershipSettings::updateUsers', []];

      $batch = [
        'operations' => $operations,
        'title'      => t('Renew membership: Period Closure'),
        'init_message' => t('Process is starting...'),
        'progress_message' => t('Processed @current out of @total. Estimated remaining time: @estimate.'),
        'finished'   => '\Drupal\association\Form\MembershipSettings::endofPeriodClosure',
      ];
      batch_set($batch);

  public static function updateMember($result, &$context)
  {
    << run some code on each Member >>
  }

  public static function updateUsers(&$context)
  {
    $id = $user->uid->value;
    if (empty($context['sandbox'])) {
      $uids = Drupal::entityQuery('user')
       ->condition('roles', 'member')
       ->execute();
      $context['sandbox']['progress'] = 0;
      $context['sandbox']['max'] = count($uids);
      $context['sandbox']['$uids'] = array_values($uids);
    }
    $uid = $context['sandbox']['$uids'][$context['sandbox']['progress']];
    $user = User::load($uid);
    if ($user) {
      $user->removeRole('member');
      $user->save();
      $context['results']['user'][] = $uid;
      $context['sandbox']['progress']++;
      $context['message'] = t('Updated user @num of @max.', ['@num' => $context['sandbox']['progress'], '@max' => $context['sandbox']['max']]);
    }
    if ($context['sandbox']['progress'] != $context['sandbox']['max']) {
      $context['finished'] = $context['sandbox']['progress'] / $context['sandbox']['max'];
    }
  }
```

In `updateMember()`, I load the content entity to update it.
In `updateUsers()`, I first retrieve all the relevant users, then in the successive calls, I remove a specific role from the user.

Lets say that in `updateMember()` I have 20 iterations and in `updateUsers()` I have 200 users.
`progress_message` is not reflecting the reality: it says that @total is 21 which is (and I get it) the total number of operations.

What can I do at the beginning of the execution of `updateUsers()` to have @total reset to 200?

Comment: The key thing to know is that the message is updated at the end of an operation, not when it starts. So if you want the message to reflect the number of users at the start of that operation, you need to run the query which gets you the count earlier. That will probably mean running that query before setting the batch, and restructuring the operations until it's portioned as you want it

Comment: When the "users" part of the batch begins, I know exactly the numbers of impacted users (I save it in `$context['sandbox']['max']`). It is just that I don't know how to update (reset?) `progress_message`at this moment...